# How to calculate the additional disease death rate (per day)?

Tags: applications

I have a susceptible bird population: 439197 and total of death cases: 45682 which happened during a period of 17 days. I want to express this death rate (infected) per day, will I just divide (439197)/(45682) and multiply by (17/365)?